# Java 11 Filter a String entry from an Array of String does not work

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

I would like to remove a String entry and an empty String from the Array of Strings.

My array of String contains the following values from index 0 to 3 - 'Name','First','Last', ""

Here is what I tried, using the stream API and Java 11 Predicate.not API:

```
Arrays.asList(myStringArray).stream()
        .filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty).or(entry -> entry.equals("Name")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would expect the entries "Name" and "" to be removed from myStringArray, what am I missing?

Comment: why exactly would "Name" be removed?

Comment: You're filtering the whole string, not manipulating it. You'll need strea.map() for that.

Comment: and change `or` to `and` ! (or maybe use a second filter - easier to read?)

Comment: You have `(!(String.isEmpty(s))) || s.equals("Name")`. Why should it remove `"Name"`?

Answer (score 1):

My question formation may have been poor, sorry about that and here's what I was looking for and it produces the desired result that I need -

```
Arrays.asList(myStringArray).stream()
    .filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty))
    .filter(Predicate.not(entry -> entry.equals("Name")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: 1) IMHO better use `Arrays.stream()` instead of `Arrays.asList().stream()`- or `Stream.of()` if not already an array - no reason to create a `List` just to use its stream; 2) the second filter should go on a line by itself (consequent formatting)

Comment: Also, for consistency, since you've already used a method reference `String::isEmpty` for the first filter, you could use a method reference for the second filter too: `"Name"::equals`.

Comment: Or just `filter(s -> !(s.isEmpty() || s.equals("Name")))`

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
var newList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myStringArray));
newList.removeAll(List.of("", "Name"));
```

Or, if you know that "Name" is *always* the first entry and "" is *always* the last entry, you could do this, which has better performance as it doesn't take any copies of anything:

```
var newList = Arrays.asList(myStringArray).subList(1, myStringArray.length - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this without doing two filter calls can be:

```
         Arrays.asList(myStringArray).stream()
           .filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty).and(entry -> !entry.equals("Name")))
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have, is that you are not taking resulting list. The thing is, the items are not removed from the array, but new list is created with items without removed items.
so just do:

````java
var newList = Arrays.asList(myStringArray).stream()
        .filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty)).filter(Predicate.not(entry -> entry.equals("Name")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());```
````